# Alias for postgis function is really slow

Tags: postgis, performance, stored-procedure

I have created an alias for st_expand function like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION expand(
geom geometry,
value double precision)
RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE my_geom geometry;
BEGIN
    my_geom =  st_expand(geom,value);
    return my_geom;
END;
 $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

This function on running my sql query returns in 1.5s, but if I directly use st_expand function - the return is in ~ 30ms.

Do note, I have to do an alias, since RDS Postgres doesn't allow me to create expand same as st_expand since they restrict creation of functions of language C.

The time to change all our sql scripts(legacy) to call st_expand and not expand is way too long. Hence creating the alias, changing to st_expand is not an option for now.

Is there any change that I can do to ensure the time is still ~30ms and not 1.5s since there's no logic done here.

Comment: What version of PostGIS are you running?

Comment: @PolyGeo Why do you tag this with [tag:PostgreSQL], if the solution is chosen specifically because my solution does not run on PostgreSQL?

Comment: @EvanCarroll I didn't apply that tag, and in fact I have just removed it, because once a question is tagged [tag:postgis] any [tag:postgresql] tag seems superfluous.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm not sure I agree with that. For instance, his problem is *unique* to RDS, and not PostreSQL it stems from not being able to create C functions. It's more specific to RDS than it is to PostGIS, and it has *nothing* to do with PostgreSQL. My suggestion would be to leave the RDS tag too.

Comment: But, yes, sorry for tagging you as you had nothing to do with PostgreSQL tag. I should have just removed it myself.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I'm not familiar with RDS, and assumed a PostGIS tag always implied PostgreSQL was the underlying DBMS.  If there are too many exceptions to that superficial understanding perhaps its [tag wiki and excerpt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/postgis/info) need a note added to that effect.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a case for an RDS tag to be created: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=rds+is%3Aquestion but if you think so then you have ample rep to do that.

Comment: @PolyGeo I can edit that tag wiki, but it'll be political. In my opinion RDS isn't PostgreSQL. But, this is highly controversial. Technically, it's a proprietary fork that merges changes from the most modern version of PostgreSQL but has added things Pg doesn't have, and removes functionality that Pg does have.

Comment: [dba.se] certainly differentiates https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-rds Also, RDS permits other databases too Amazon Aurora | MySQL | MariaDB | Oracle | SQL Server (but none of them run PostGIS).

Comment: The distinction is not something that I will lose sleep over but if the PostGIS "sub-community" (and those other "sub-communities") here thinks that it is important then they should feel free to try enhancing their tagging in whatever way suits them best.  I try to only influence tagging decisions when I think it is making questions significantly harder for potential answerers to find them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use an SQL wrapper instead.  plpgsql wrappers tend to be slower since they are not inlined and you are forcing an intermediary step too which can get slow the bigger the geometry.

So write your function as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION expand(geom geometry,value double precision)
RETURNS geometry AS
$$
 SELECT st_expand(geom,value);
$$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this another way by there is a file called `legacy.sql`

```
postgis-2.2/legacy.sql
```

Warning don't actually use these unless you're on Postgis 2.2 If you've got 3.3, look for your own `postgis-2.3/legacy.sql`

```
-- Deprecation in 1.2.3
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Expand(box2d,float8)
  RETURNS box2d
  AS '$libdir/postgis-2.2', 'BOX2D_expand'
  LANGUAGE 'c' IMMUTABLE STRICT;

-- Deprecation in 1.2.3
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Expand(box3d,float8)
  RETURNS box3d
  AS '$libdir/postgis-2.2', 'BOX3D_expand'
  LANGUAGE 'c' IMMUTABLE STRICT;

-- Deprecation in 1.2.3
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Expand(geometry,float8)
  RETURNS geometry
  AS '$libdir/postgis-2.2', 'LWGEOM_expand'
  LANGUAGE 'c' IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

So you run

```
psql -d <database> -f <path to legacy.sql>
```

Comment: We have Amazon RDS, they don't allow us to run this. But this was the first solution I thought, it definitely works. Can't upvote since I don't have points, but this is a legitimate answer